# Finding a recurrence relation for this recursive function?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

Consider the following function:

```
g(A, i, j) {
    print("g", i, j);
    n := j-i+1;
    if (n == 2) {
        if (A[i] > A[j]) swap A[i] and A[j];
    }
    else {
        for(k := 0 to n/4-1) swap A[i+n/4+k] with A[i+n/2+k];

        // swap 2nd and 3rd quarters
        g(A, i, i+n/2-1); // recurse on 1st and 2nd quarters
        g(A, i+n/2, j); // recurse on 3rd and 4th quarters
        g(A, i+n/4, i+3n/4-1); // recurse on 2nd and 3rd quarters
    }
}
```

How would I deduce a recurrence relation for the runtime of the function g? I've seen that the answer is

> T(n) = 3T(n / 2) + O(n).

In this expression, does T(n) mean "time?" Where does the n / 2 come from here? And, more generally, how do I find recurrences like these?

Comment: Improve your pseudo code it seems incomplete.

Comment: Just confirming, but `f` is irrelevant here, right?

Comment: yes f is irrelevannt

Answer (score 2):

You can read the recurrence

> T(n) = 3T(n / 2) + O(n)

as defining some function T(n) that determines how much time it takes for the function `g` to run on an array that contains a total of n elements. Because the function `g` is recursive, the definition of T(n) is recursive as well.

Here, the 3T(n / 2) means "there are three recursive calls made, each of which is to a subproblem of size n / 2." To see why this is, note that in the recursive case, `g` makes three calls to itself on the ranges

```
g(A, i, i+n/2-1); // recurse on 1st and 2nd quarters
g(A, i+n/2, j); // recurse on 3rd and 4th quarters
g(A, i+n/4, i+3n/4-1); // recurse on 2nd and 3rd quarters
```

The total number of elements in each range is n / 2 (do you see why?), hence the 3T(n / 2) bit.

The "+ O(n)" comes in because the algorithm, in the recursive case, does a linear amount of work independently of the work done to make the recursive calls. That comes in from the `for` loop above the recursive calls.

Once you have a recurrence like this one, you can use the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) to convert the recursive definition of T(n) into a direct bound on how T(n) behaves. Here, the runtime works out to

> T(n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub> 3</sup>),

which we obtain by looking at the cases of the master theorem to see which one applies.

Comment: how is the elements in each range n/2? in the third call isn't it n/4?

Comment: It's the range from (i + n/4) to (i + 3n/4), which is n/2 total elements.